# What is meaning of tilde(~) symbol mean in the context of this PHP documentation page?

Tags: php, floating-point, double, decimal, tilde

Consider below statement from the [PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#language.types.float) and let me know the meaning of **tilde(~) symbol** used in this context.

> The size of a float is platform-dependent, although a maximum of
>   ~1.8e308 with a precision of roughly 14 decimal digits is a common
>   value (the 64 bit IEEE format).

Also, let me know whether the meaning of **tilde(~) symbol** have the meaning of **negation/not** in other contexts of PHP language as in Mathematics(For example, ~A means "not A.")?

Can the **tilde(~) symbol** used in mathematical or logical expression is PHP? If yes provide me some relative working code example of the same. If not explain me the reason behind it?

Comment: Afaik, the ~ symbol is used to convey the meaning of "roughly"/"approximately" when used with numbers in general. I'd be surprised if it had a different, PHP specific meaning here?

Comment: @SerialKisser: yes, the ~ can be used in mathematical or logical expression is PHP. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Edit:** I've submitted a patch to fix it to the PHP documentation and it got accepted, the new phrasing is "approximately 1.9e308".

It means "approximately" in this context, even though the sentence is poorly phrased, due to the very ambiguousness you cite.

There's no mathematical or programmatic meaning behind the symbol in this particular context, although as you said, in a program, `~` means the bitwise not operator.

My guess is that it was written without thought of the other meanings of `~` preceding a number.

Comment: The ~ is a bitwise operator. When used in code it does not mean "approximately". It flips the bits of a numbers.

Comment: @MrGlass That is correct, but this isn't in code. Read the question carefully.

Comment: @MrGlass: `~` **in texts** is often used to replace the unicode code point U+2245 (which can probably not be found on most keyboards), and that means "approximately equal to". And that is exactly the meaning it has here: **approx. 1.8e308**.

Answer (score -1):

The `~` operator in PHP is a ["bitwise not"](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). It reverses the assigned bits (`0`'s become `1`'s and `1`'s become `0`'s).

*edited to correct "bitwise".*

Comment: Bitwise, not logical. The logical `not` operator is `!`

Comment: @Leigh, you're right. I corrected the link description.

Comment: The meaning of the operator is totally irrelevant here. The question is about the quoted text, and there it means "approximately".

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, SerialKisser also asked "Can the **tilde(~) symbol** used in mathematical or logical expression is PHP? If yes provide me some relative working code example of the same. If not explain me the reason behind it?" I answered that specific question, which is the **only** question related to PHP in his post.